# How to access a CD/DVD drive over the network?

Tags: linux, optical-drive

The CD/DVD drive of my notebook is broken. However, the drive from my desktop computer is working perfectly.

How can I access the CD/DVD drive from my desktop computer over the network? I want to put a DVD disc there and access it from my notebook.

Both computers have Gentoo/Linux. (but the solution ought to work on any Linux distribution)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I feel like a Samba / NFS setup is kind of a big hammer for this little nail. I found a [blog post on this topic](https://iseborn.eu/2014/10/09/sharing-a-cdrom-over-the-network-with-ubuntu-14-04/) which shows the use of a tool called nbd -- network block device. To use it, setup the server and client.

(The tutorial is written for Ubuntu with a CD device at `/dev/cdrom`, so you may need to adjust for your setup.)

**On the server side (with the CDROM):**

```
sudo apt-get install nbd-server
sudo adduser nbd cdrom
```

(You may get a warning about no configured exports - ignore it, we'll set one up below.)

Edit the `/etc/nbd-server/config` file:

```
[generic]
  group     = cdrom
  allowlist = true
[cdrom]
  exportname = /dev/cdrom
  readonly   = true
```

Then: `sudo /etc/init.d/nbd-server restart`

**On the client side (access the server's CDROM):**

```
sudo apt-get install nbd-client
```

Now map the block device (where `192.168.1.100` is the ip address of the server):

```
sudo nbd-client 192.168.1.100 -name cdrom /dev/nbd0
```

Now you can mount `/dev/nbd0` as if it was a CDROM on the client:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom   # if it doesn't already exist
sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/nbd0 /mnt/cdrom
```

Or grab an ISO:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/nbd0 of=~/disc.iso
```

Comment: This is a better write up than the chatty original, thanks!

Comment: I was able to follow these instructions with *zero* hiccups on two archlinux machines (archlinux bundles server and client as `nbd`). It's not perfect, though: my software can tell that it's not a real drive. I'm trying to play a bluray somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Try sharing it over samba:

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

and

```
[cdrom]
comment = CD Drive
path = /mnt/cdrom
public = no
writable = no
```

Comment: +1 from me. I already did this using samba oce and it works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, this is not working. The log inside `/var/log/` says: `'/dev/sr0' is not a directory, when connecting to [cdrom]` (I've renamed `[public]` to `[cdrom]`)

Comment: Changing `/dev/cdrom` into `/mnt/cdrom` (or whatever the mountpoint is) solves the issue.

Comment: How do you unmount the cdrom though once smb grabs it?  like to replace it with another disc

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought about sharing the `/dev/cdrom` (actually, `/dev/sr0`) using either [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_(protocol)) or [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

Then I tried that, and it does not work. Raw devices can't be shared using these technologies.

However, I can mount the cdrom somewhere (`/mnt/cdrom` and `/media/cdrom` are common places) and then share the mount point.

Using `sshfs` is easy to setup, as it doesn't require root permissions nor any configuration file. It's also "safe", as the file access permissions will be basically the same as the logged in ssh user. However, using `NFS` will lead to better performance (because it has less overhead, as it doesn't encrypt any data).