# CentOS as media server

Tags: windows-xp, centos, vlc-media-player, streaming, netbook

I have a headless CentOS 6.4 box with no GUI installed, and a WinXP netbook without a DVD drive.  How can I stream a DVD from the CentOS box over the network to watch it on the netbook?  (I imagine this can be done using vlc on both ends somehow?)

Answer (score 2):

I use PLEX media server. No head required and it can stream to pretty much anything. Just log into the web interface. http://www.plexapp.com/
As for running the DVD itself... Rip it and put it in your video library on the CentOS box.

Comment: So Plex will do the ripping?

Comment: I am pretty sure all you would have to do is 'copy' the contents of the disk to a directory where plex is looking for your video files. The PLEX server can read .ts files without a problem and should be able to pick them up and stream them. 

So technically no, you would have to manually copy the contents to a directory on your CentOS box but yes, PLEX will handle the files without having to manually do 'ripping'.

Comment: Here is some info on converting the files to MKV for plex using handbrake: http://forums.plexapp.com/index.php/topic/40457-best-setting-for-ripping-dvds/

Comment: So...Plex should be able to read the DVD directly without ripping, yes?

Comment: I have not pointed my server directly to the dvd itself but I would assume that it could be possible. Try it out, its all free.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably [create an image of the DVD](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-ISO-File-in-Linux) on the CentOS box and then copy that image to your netbook and [mount it using virtual drive software](http://www.itworld.com/consumerization-it/354939/mount-iso-files-virtual-cd-drives-microsofts-free-utility).

But if you prefer to stream your DVDs, and your network is fast enough, you can always [mount a samba share of the DVD drive](https://superuser.com/questions/316745/how-to-access-a-cd-dvd-drive-over-the-network) on CentOS and then [connect to that share on the netbook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308582) and launch any [DVD playing software](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html). (VLC works great)

Comment: I'm going to try this first just because I'd like to test out Samba anyway.  Thanks.